# SecCertificateCreateWithData always returns nil. how can i resolve it?

Tags: swift, certificate, x509certificate, pki

In the code below, `dotP7b` is a base64 encoded string of certificate. We want to create certificate using the `SecCertificateCreateWithData` function. But it always returns nil. One issue I have found out that conversion of base64 string to DER. I have converted it already.

I am deleting public key in each call.

```
guard let cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, dotP7b.data(using: .utf8)! as CFData) else { return }
```

My `dotP7b` String is given below:

`MIIEoDCCA4igAwIBAgIUEMYX7c9TTvsXIKxBls0XOKsYEi0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL%0ABQAwgYMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJEMSQwIgYDVQQKExtCYW5nbGFkZXNoIENvbXB1dGVy%0AIENvdW5jaWwxHTAbBgNVBAsTFENlcnRpZnlpbmcgQXV0aG9yaXR5MS8wLQYDVQQD%0AEyZCQ0MgU3ViLUNBIGZvciBDbGFzcyAwIENlcnRpZmljYXRlcy1HMzAeFw0yMzA1%0AMTAwODIzNDhaFw0yNDA1MTAwODIzNDhaMHExCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJEMQwwCgYDVQQK%0AEwNCQ0MxCzAJBgNVBAsTAkNBMQ0wCwYDVQQREwQxMjA3MQ4wDAYDVQQHEwVEaGFr%0AYTEOMAwGA1UEBRMFNjMxNzExGDAWBgNVBAMTD1NpZGRpcXVyIFJhaG1hbjCCASIw%0ADQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALLUtSUV09QvVH%2BHwfKF4OeSfqm1%0AiHLwSzT4WBGlxAXq%2BWDsUz8OwUfsHF8Em0C%2Fio%2BBbt3d6TKkHpB1M6UcZMFsejqk%0AwkdLDcCo5ByWPxCaZcZcaeSqvzdN17jjdYFLETxLHPelQ2TKSTAo1XGoPRb9iAcF%0AUxm1umK3gw42DIYickz4ConFuNY5UgdozVZYhOpb5d1tzg0UZYsCoWD4cEvM18KY%0A1T93aQngOeXSCm4WMAp8ilTs%2Bv8437g1gO18J3o7kSlrjPxvWSC4I94ZZgI4bTer%0A7%2BAo4x%2FrUxsAjpP384FneJaxdNAuXVL857OMBA9PRQn7T25TDZ1Jh858D%2BUCAwEA%0AAaOCARswggEXMA4GA1UdDwEB%2FwQEAwIGwDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMHwGCCsGAQUF%0ABwEBBHAwbjAlBggrBgEFBQcwAYYZaHR0cDovL29jc3AuYmNjLWNhLmdvdi5iZDBF%0ABggrBgEFBQcwAoY5aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXBvLmJjYy1jYS5nb3YuYmQvY2VydHMvQkND%0ALVN1Yi1DQS1DbGFzczAtRzMuY2VyMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFIRvdFq0TzkwH%2FpFlDjr%0AMzf4yQ8WMDkGA1UdHwQyMDAwLqAsoCqGKGh0dHA6Ly9jcmwuYmNjLWNhLmdvdi5i%0AZC9CQ0NDQTIwMjJHMy5jcmwwHQYDVR0OBBYEFIaHga8kHUVnv%2FnaOocB2dHB1mwj%0AMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQDEQU0ByMWDKXyWaEx6dMaLtRdZk0iidZJmgPCf%0AH8fJoOeu9xCEYMSloJMsgkimikEeOktticjRYxu98J3xG7p4xX6%2FuR194asgOpPh%0ABjijaW536NM43oeHFrpcor2lp8lZnJEBq8eoqtdq6Zhl8%2B1jSBgaOLm5%2Fz%2BDjwlM%0APNXEQ5DTeZ6SY8b3bCXtsXD2gwrZMLR8Ea9ZebvJXff1xNkNln4azGFvba4jsLnd%0AO7bOnGcjW5vQmC6llOWrhDCZft9MzKVkQa9v3tFpN1i9DK0XiVqum3rb8U%2BJzO5E%0AMFrVaKiEH%2FCt%2FfsQqymEpE8YhwnLqWC%2Fz1tuo7kMXv5uV%2Br0`

and it's url encoded.